# How to delete auto-generated id data in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
async created () {
    const sn = await db.collection('forms').get()
    sn.forEach(v => {
      const { title, content } = v.data()
      this.forms.push({
        title, content, id: v.id
      })
      console.log(v.id)
    })
  },
  del () {
    db.collection('forms').doc().delete()
  }
}
```

I succeeded in reading the data and getting an ID. But I don't know what to put in the doc() to delete.

Comment: What. *do* you know about the document you want to delete? As a human: if you look in the Firestore console and click through the documents, how do you know which one you want to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew the ID of the document then it would have been as easy as this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("forms").doc("docId").delete()
```

But in your case, you would have to add an additional step of getting the document ID. I'm not sure about your db structure but for example, let's say you want to delete a form submitted by a user named "john" (you must store the name in document). Then you can fetch the document (and it's ID) this way:

```
const formDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection("forms").where("name", "==", "john").get()
if (formDoc.exists) {
  await firebase.firestore().collection("forms").doc(formDoc.id).delete()
}
```

Again the name may not be unique so it's better to rely on user UIDs for this. If you are using Firebase Authentication then please add a field in document called uid having the value of user's UID in it. Then you can use UID instead of name in the query.